# How Can I Use Roslyn in an ASP.NET MVC 5 App?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, roslyn

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 app (5.2.7 to be exact) targetting .NET Framework 4.7.2. I'm trying to add a feature for validation rules on objects. I have a bunch of conditions that I transform into a C# script which I want to evaluate using `CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync`.

I have a prototype of this working in LINQPad and was trying to port it into the main project. Because the main project was being developed on C# 5 in VS2013, I decided it was time to upgrade to C# 7.3 and VS2017, so I did. After cleaning up everything after the upgrade, I decided to implement the prototype.

I first added the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting` NuGet package to the main project, but when I tried to run the application, I got all kinds of exceptions from what I presume was library conflicts between MVC 5 and whatever the package dependencies were.

I then reverted and tried making a separate project in which to have the validation rules code. When I ran the application, it loaded and everything seemed fine, until I tried to trigger a validation rule. At that point it threw an exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

In a round about way I'm back to the problem of the main project trying to load the NuGet package.

So,... Is there a way I can make the two work together or no? If no, what are my next choices to make it work? Migrate to ASP.NET Core? I intend to do that in the future, just trying to avoid it right now because the solution is rather large, after 4 years of working on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative, and proper, option is really to migrate to ASP.NET Core. Since 3.0 is around the corner I will probably do so at that time.

Comment: I didn't see your question at the time of asking, but I had a similar-ish issue that I solved by using an older version of Roslyn and its dependencies than the latest that was provided by nuget..NET Core 3 looks promising, but it feels like it's still dealing with a lot of little growing pains.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit older of a question and I just moved on. I've been using .NET Core since 2.0 on other projects and really enjoy it, its just that this one is so massive I'm not looking forward to migrating it, but I think I've come to the point in the road where I can't squeeze more out of it so an upgrade is in order. Do you remember which version of Roslyn you had luck with?

Comment: I believe it was version 2.0 of the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.X libraries.